# Is it possible to hierarchically label a matplotlib (pyplot) bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I've managed to make the following bar plot using matplotlib.pyplot.

[image]

The plot comes from an aggregated PANDAS DataFrame, printed below. Note that each bar in the bar-plot corresponds to a value in the `mean` column. Also note that the values are **not** zero, but that PANDAS outputs `0` and `-0` when floats are very small.

```
Group Local Global Attn  mean
ASub  LD    GD     Attn    -0
                   Dist    -0
            GS     Attn    -0
                   Dist    -0
      LS    GD     Attn    -0
                   Dist    -0
            GS     Attn    -0
                   Dist    -0
DSub  LD    GD     Attn    -0
                   Dist     0
            GS     Attn    -0
                   Dist    -0
      LS    GD     Attn    -0
                   Dist    -0
            GS     Attn    -0
                   Dist    -0
```

I would like to label the x-axis of my bar plot hierarchically, in a manner corresponding to the labels above. In other words, the left half of the x-axis corresponds to the `ASub` group. The left half of the `ASub` group corresponds to the `LD` level of the  `Local` factor, and so on...

Can this be done?

**EDIT:**

I think I should probably clarify exactly what I want. I'd like for there to be several labels, progressing from most general (Group) to most specific (Attn), similar to the organization on the left 4 columns of the DataFrame above.

Comment: Another pandas user raised some ideas about this also: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2088

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On master this is implemented (i used random data for 'mean'), see image at the bottom.
If you prefer not to upgrade you can also set it manually:

```
In [143]: ax = df.plot(kind='bar')

In [144]: ax.set_xticklabels(['|'.join(t) for t in df.index])
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
 In [167]: ax = df.plot(kind='bar')

 In [168]: ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.format(names=False))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good "plan B", but it doesn't really correspond to what I'm trying to do.  I'm interested in reproducing the tree-like label structure from the pandas DataFrame printout above, such that it can clearly be seen that the `Local` factor is a subset of the `Group` factor, and so forth.  Any way to do that?

Comment: I don't know if you received any of my previous comments, but your code works -- I was just being stupid =).  In any case, thank you very much!  This is perfect!