# Pandas, hierarchically labeling bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, charts

Asking the exact question as [Is it possible to hierarchically label a matplotlib (pyplot) bar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427056/is-it-possible-to-hierarchically-label-a-matplotlib-pyplot-bar-plot?rq=1), but for Pandas instead, as the answer is not there.

[This](https://gist.github.com/suntong/0e04741f28d999eafc04) is as far I can go myself. You can see that at `In [10]`, I was trying to duplicate the solution from above, but it doesn't work for Pandas. In fact I don't see my labels from "A" and "B" at all.

I want two levels of labeling, "A" as the first level and "B" as the secondary one. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to set your index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']*2,
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                         'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                  'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                  'D' : np.random.randn(8)})


>>> df.set_index(['A', 'B']).plot(rot=90)
```

[image]